# randomSearchCv/gridSearchCv freeze with n_jobs>1

Tags: python-3.6, gridsearchcv

If I use gridSearchCv with nJobs>1 my code seems to freeze: the processes are still running but don't use CPU, it seems they are in wait. I don't know how to solve this, please help me.

```
 --- modulename: selectors, funcname: select
selectors.py(366):             if timeout is None:
selectors.py(367):                 timeout = None
selectors.py(374):             ready = []
selectors.py(375):             try:
selectors.py(376):                 fd_event_list = self._poll.poll(timeout)
```

Comment: then if I use ctrl+c I get this:

  File "/home/davide/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 427, in result
    self._condition.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295, in wait
    waiter.acquire()

Comment: how many number of cores  you have in your system ?... if you use `njobs=-1` then it will eat all of your cpu...   ** n_jobs : int or None, optional (default=None)
Number of jobs to run in parallel. None means 1 unless in a joblib.parallel_backend context. -1 means using all processors. See Glossary for more details.**

Comment: My system has 8 core, I often use -1  because I want to speed up taining but it freeze

Comment: It is the problem with the dataset.... and the model that you have selected .... could you paste your gridsearch code here ... we can optimize that....

Comment: It's not a dataset problem, I use 4 different datasets and get the same results. My gridRandomSearch below:
`def getRandomSearchCvAndFit(self,X_train,y_train,model, hyperparameters):
        random = RandomizedSearchCV(model, hyperparameters,scoring=["balanced_accuracy","accuracy"], refit='balanced_accuracy', n_iter=100,cv=10,verbose=0,n_jobs=-1)
        # Fit grid search
        random.fit(X_train, y_train)
        self.printResultsSearch(random)
        return random`

Comment: I have the problem only with keras neural network, with other algorithm like XGBoost there is no problem. Keras neural network with 1 job works

Comment: as it is not fully developed inside sklearn .. so you will face problems